# Can heat be used to create charge carriers in the depletion region of a pn junction as is done by light with the photoelectric effect?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, photoelectric-effect

I have watched some videos on how Photovoltaic cells produce electricity and it seems to be by the production of charge carriers in the depletion region due to the photoelectric efect which are then drawn by opposite sides of the pn junction creating a voltage difference.
Why doesn't the same effect seem to be observed for charge carriers created randomly from heat?

Answer (score 0):

It does produce charge carriers, but at thermal equilibrium the rate at which they travel in each direction across the junction is equal. This is captured theoretically in the [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation). If this was not so, you could make a [perpetual motion machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion). We have a great deal of evidence that this cannot be done, which we capture in the [second law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics).

When you illuminate a photoelectric cell, the photocurrent adds to the thermal current, but only in one direction. The thermal current remains important, though, as the generated voltage assists it. This limits the voltage you can get from the cell: the open circuit voltage equals the voltage at which the assisted thermal current balances the photocurrent. The optimum voltage for power extraction is a bit lower.

Comment: Isn't the magnetic field at the two sides of the depletion regions that draws the charge carriers at opposite directions? Why would they travel in both directions equally in the case of thermal equilibrium. Also why does the photocurrent add to the thermal current only in one direction?

Comment: Adding light generates carriers, but does not cause (directly) recombination. So it adds in one direction only.